# Remove puncts from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis, punctuation

I want to remove all punctuations and latin characters from a dataframe with Tweets for sentiment analysis. The code is the following. I want to remove the punctuations from the column but the code removes the text and only puncts are left!! Any suggestions?

remove_puncts = lambda x: re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+", "", str(x))

df['new'] = df.Tweet.apply(remove_puncts)

Comment: Please provide a [MRE]

Comment: Please check again [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642016/16343464), the regex works as expected. Thus your problem is currently *not reproducible*. Please provide further details, ideally a minimal example that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df['Tweet'].str.replace(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+', '', regex=True)
```

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tweet': ['abc, def; (hij)!?', '[w] x/y: z']})
df
```

```
               Tweet
0  abc, def; (hij)!?
1         [w] x-y: z
```

output:

```
>>> df['Tweet'].str.replace(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+', '', regex=True)
0    abc def hij
1         w xy z
```

Comment: @TimRoberts Well, I have, and the regex *should* work. There must be something else wrong or missing information. I can't now, but I'll try to provide a working example later

Comment: No, the question was "how to I REMOVE the punctuation".  You are solving "how do I KEEP only the punctuation."

Comment: @TimRoberts either your are not familiar with regexes or you skimmed too fast through the Q/A. The answer is doing exactly what OP wants. The `^` symbol in the regex inverses the match. I edited my answer to demonstrate that it works. The problem is not reproducible and OP must have another issue.

Comment: No worries. I just hope OP will provide more information.

Comment: It keeps only the punctuations. That's the problem. I used other ways to solve this as well but all of them return only the punctuations. The tweets are in greek language, I don't know if there is a problem with encoding or smth else :/

Comment: Can you please provide the actual data? We understand the problem, the thing is we cannot reproduce it. We need an example for that.

Comment: For example in the following sentence I want to keep the greek text and remove "alert" and numbers but it removes all the text and keeps only the "alert" word and the numbers. 

df['Tweet'][1]
'ακουστε παρεμβαση τεως διοικητη νοσοκομειου αχεπα δημητρη γακη ανατρεπτικο δελτιο alert ανδρεα καψαμπελη 26072021 εμβολιο'

  df['New'][1]
'          alert   26072021 '

Comment: Well, this is normal, Greek is not ASCII, so you explicitely ask to remove it with your regex. To remove ASCII and keep Greek, use this regex `[a-zA-Z]`, if you also want to remove punctuation, please provide an example.

Comment: Well, it worked :D It removed all non-greek characters and number by adding 0-9. I usually work with english text so I was confused.

Comment: That's why it is important to try to *understand* what a command/code is doing, and also next time when you ask a question it would help a lot if you directly provide an example of what you want to do (input / expected output). This would have saved us a lot of time ;)